# MVVM where to put my class

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0, mvvm

I used a customized TreeViewItem class named TreeViewItemWithCheckbox. The code is copied from here
[Treeview with checkbox bind by different lists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7594678/treeview-with-checkbox-bind-by-different-lists?rq=1)

It works fine. My question is: with MVVM which folder should this class be put into? Model, ViewModel, or View?

Regards,

Comment: While in your case this would make most sense to be in the "View" folder, I would say consider the option to just make a separate folder like "Custom Controls" or so. MVVM does not mean everything has to be in one of them folders. Grouping Custom Controls away could help keep the View folder with Just View's and also might be easier to work through the Project or to extract all them custom controls into a separate module or so if using Prism or likes.

Comment: Thank you all for the answer. i appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the `TreeViewItem` is really a view related function, this class would be part of the View.  In general, any visual "control" should be a pure View related function.

Answer (score 2):

I personally would go for none of them, I'd put it squarely in a user control Library, try always to keep the view empty of code, or at least in a separate folder